# Partition function for a general Ising model as Gaussian integral

Tags: analysis, dynamical-systems, quantum-mechanics, gaussian-integral, statistical-mechanics

Consider the Hamiltonian of Ising model

$$H= - \sum_{x,y} J_{x,y}\sigma_x \sigma_y -  \sum_x h\sigma_x$$

where $\sigma_x$ can be $1$ or $-1$ and the number of sites is finite ( i.e. there are a finite number of $x,y$ ) and where $x,y$ are points of the a $d$-lattice with side $L$ (i.e. $x,y \in \mathbb{Z} \cap[-L/2,L/2].$
So the partiction function is
$$Z=\sum_{\sigma}e^{-\beta H}=\sum_{\sigma}e^{\beta\sum_{x,y} J_{x,y}\sigma_x \sigma_y} e^{\sum_x h\sigma_x}$$
where the sum is over all the possible choice of $\sigma=\pm 1$.

The goal is to write the partiction function as a Gaussian integral using the following formula$$\int e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{n}A_{ij} x_i x_j+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}B_i x_i} d^nx=\int e^{-\frac{1}{2}\vec{x}^T \mathbf{A} \vec{x}+\vec{B}^T \vec{x}} d^nx= \sqrt{ \frac{(2\pi)^n}{\det{A}} }e^{\frac{1}{2}\vec{B}^{T}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\vec{B}}$$
in view of the fact that $e^{\beta\sum_{x,y} J_{x,y}\sigma_x \sigma_y}$ has the form $e^{\frac{1}{2}\vec{B}^{T}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\vec{B}}$ ( thinking $\sigma=(\sigma_{x_1},...)$ as a vector with $L^d$ components and $J=(J_{xy})$ as a matrix $L^d\times L^d$) .

Now, what i read on the notes is that

$$e^{\beta\sum_{x,y} J_{x,y}\sigma_x \sigma_y}= (2\pi)^ {L^d}(detJ)^{-1/2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\prod_{x} d \varphi_x e^{-\frac{1}{2\beta}\sum_{x,y}\varphi_x J^{-1}_{xy}\varphi_y + \sum_{x}\varphi_x \sigma_x}.$$

To verify the last formula I tried to calculate the integral in the right head side using the classical techniques for the Gaussian integral (
completion of the square), but I didn't found the last formula. So my question is: is there something wrong with the last expression for $e^{\beta\sum_{x,y} J_{x,y}\sigma_x \sigma_y}$ as Gaussian integral?

Comment: At first sight, your formula for $e^{\beta\sum_{x,y} J_{x,y}\sigma_x \sigma_y}$ seems correct to me (assuming that by $J_{xy}^{-1}$ you mean the $x,y$ element of the matrix $J^{-1}$), apart from the fact that you should have $\sqrt{2\pi}$ rather than $2\pi$ in the prefactor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, my mistake: it's $\sqrt 2\pi$. What I can't do when I calculate the integral is "delete" the factor $1/2$ in the exponential. How can I delete that term?

Comment: Oh yes, right, there is a missing factor of $1/2$ in the exponent in the left-hand side... (Compare with (8.61) in [this book](http://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook).)

Comment: Really thank you for the reference. I just saw that the Hamiltonian considered in that book has the factor $1/2$ that I needed, so I think that in this way everything works as I  wanted. Is it possible that my teacher wrote that expression in my question really quickly, without carefulness about factors, constants, just to show us how to proceed? At the end, the important stuff is how the Gaussian integrals are used in the expression of partition function of Ising model, right?

Comment: Yes, or maybe he was summing over edges in the graph, in which case all pairs $x,y$ in the left-hand side appear only once and the $1/2$ is not needed... Hard to know for sure. But yes, the important point in this problem is the observation that this trick allows you to reformulate the Ising model as a perturbed Gaussian Free Field.